# Python Pandas rows merging different column values include Binary or Yes or No values

Tags: python, pandas

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Eswar   IT  Yes
Eswar   Admin   No


Column1 Column2 Column3
Eswar   IT,Admin    No
```

I need this as

Where Yes/No becomes No
Or
1/0 become 0

Comment: what if `Yogi` had two `Yes`?

Comment: Yes No be like No, Yes Yes be like Yes, No No be like No

Answer (score 1):

You can aggreagte values by `join` and `min`, it working for `Yes/No` and `1/0` values very well:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Column1', as_index=False)
         .agg(Column2=('Column2', ','.join), Column3=('Column3', 'min')))
print (df1)
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   Eswar  IT,Admin      No
```

---

```
print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3  Col4 Col5
0   Eswar      IT     Yes    10    a
1   Eswar   Admin      No    10    a


df1 = (df.groupby(['Column1', 'Col4', 'Col5'], as_index=False)
         .agg(Column2=('Column2', ','.join), Column3=('Column3', 'min')))
print (df1)

  Column1  Col4 Col5   Column2 Column3
0   Eswar    10    a  IT,Admin      No
```

Comment: What if I had muntiple columns like with same values,       

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
Eswar IT Yes Account Tax
Eswar Admin No Account Tax

Comment: @Eswar - Then add it to `groupby` like `df.groupby(['Column1', 'col4', 'col5'], as_index=False)`

Comment: Error:  Groupby() got multiple values for argument ‘as_index’

Comment: @Eswar - added sample to answer, for me working well.